# Сон и успение — этимологически однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Считаются ли слова *сон* и *успение* этимологически однокоренными?

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, значение слова корень [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&all=x). Создаётся впечатление, что в своих вопросах Вы путаете значение этого слова в грамматике (п.6 по ссылке) и другое (начало, источник и т.п. — п.5 по ссылке).

Comment: Лучше всё же сказать "этимoлoгичecки poдcтвeнные" – этo cлoвa, пpoизoшeдшиe oт oднoгo и тoгo жe cлoвa, нo в coвpeмeннoм языкe имeющиe paзныe кopни. Есть такой термин. http://www.textologia.ru/slovari/lingvisticheskie-terminy/etimologicheskie-rodstvenniki/?n=2137&q=486

Answer (score 1):

Слова **сон** и **успение** не являются однокоренными, потому что в слове **сон** корень *сон*, а в слове **успение** — *успени* (чтобы уверенно находить корни слов, можно воспользоваться одним из подходящих словарей, например, Тихонова). Эти слова связаны семантически и этимологически и являются родственными.

Answer (score 1):

Речь может идти только об историческом родстве слов,  они не однокоренные.

[СОН](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD)

> Происходит от праслав. *sъnъ, от кот. в числе прочего произошли:
>   др.-русск., ст.-слав. сънъ (др.-греч. ὕπνος), др.-русск. въ сънѣхъ,
>   русск., укр. сон (род. п. сна), белор. сон (род. сна), болг. сън,
>   сербохорв. са̏н (род. п. сна)̏, словенск. sǝ̀n (род. п. snà), чешск.,
>   словацк. sen, польск. sen (род. п. sna), в.-луж. són (род. п. sоnа,
>   sna), н.-луж. soń ж. (род. п. sni). Праслав. *sъnъ из *sърnъ,
>   родственного *sъраti (см. спать), а также лит. sãpnas «сон,
>   сновидение», sãpnis — то же, латышск. sapnis «сновидение», др.-инд.
>   svápnas «сон, сновидение», авест. ẋvafna- (м.) — то же, арм. kΏun,
>   греч. ὕπνος м. «сон», лат. somnus — то же, тохар. А ṣpäm, В ṣpäne
>   «сон», др.-исл. svefn, ирл. súan, алб. gjumë. Ср. также лат. somnium
>   «сон», греч. ἐνύπνιον, др.-инд. svápnyam, др.-русск., ст.-слав. съниѥ
>   «сновидение».

[УСПЕНИЕ](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

> Происходит от др.-русск. усъпениіе «засыпание, сон; смерть, кончина;
>   церк. праздник» от у- + спать, калькирует греч. κοίμησις τῆς Θεοτόκου.